# Read image from s3 server and process it from rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image-processing, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a image in s3 bucket and url to access it.
I want to read the image from the s3 and to create a thumbnail icon and push the thumbnail_icon to s3.

If the image is in local, I can read the image and convert it to `StringIO`. After that I can push the `StringIO` to create thumbnail image in s3:

```
item = File.read(url)
data_io = StringIO.new(item)
s3_connection.interface.put(data_io, ...)
```

how can I open remote file and process it?

`File.open(remote_url)` returns `No such file or directory`

with `OpenURI` I can read the file. But I couldn't convert it to `StringIO`

```
response = open(remote_url) #Tempfile
data_io = StringIO.new(response) 
#can't convert Tempfile into String`
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1):

The StringIO initialize method expects a string as the only parameter. The object you are giving it is a Tempfile. Try this:

```
data_io = StringIO.new(response.read)
```

Comment: Thanks it works well. Is there a way to read a `pdf` file and put it to s3 in image format?